# What can I do about "null is not an object (evaluating 'p')" when creating an AWS Lambda?

Tags: aws-lambda

I’m trying to create an AWS Lambda. I’ve written a small Python 2.7 script with a single dependency (boto3). To turn the script into a Lambda, I run the following steps:

1. I run `lambda deploy` with the [python-lambda library](https://pypi.org/project/python-lambda/) to construct an uploadable ZIP file. For some reason it fails at the step where it actually uploads the file, but it produces a ZIP.
2. I upload the ZIP file to the “Code” tab of my AWS Lambda page.
3. I click “Save and Test”.

I expect this to run my script and produce some output – and indeed, this has worked for several dozen iterations. But I made a small code change to my script (changing two lines, diff below) – and now, I get an unfriendly red error message:

> null is not an object (evaluating 'p')

Here’s what it looks like:

[image]

To me, that sounds more like a JavaScript error than a Python one – what can I do to fix this?

---

I’ve already tried:

- Creating a new ZIP file with the new file and uploading it again – no difference.
- Uploading to an S3 bucket, and loading the code from there. My ZIP file is 9.4MB, so I think direct upload should be okay – either way, makes no difference.
- Creating a fresh Lambda function – the error follows me to the new one.
- Changing the code. Comparing the contents of the ZIP files, if I ignore compiled PYC files, this is the only difference:

  ```
  diff -r /Users/chana/repos/terraform-lambda/bisect/2017-02-02-161207-my_lambda_function/service.py /Users/chana/repos/terraform-lambda/bisect/2017-02-02-161437-my_lambda_function/service.py
  25,26c25,26
  <     subprocess.check_call(['unzip', '/tmp/terraform_0.8.5_linux_amd64.zip'])
  <     subprocess.check_call(['terraform', '--version'])
  ---
  >     subprocess.check_call(['unzip', '/tmp/terraform_0.8.5_linux_amd64.zip', '-d', '/tmp/terraform_0.8.5'])
  >     subprocess.check_call(['/tmp/terraform_0.8.5/terraform', '--version'])
  ```

  If I revert to the version before this change, I no longer get the error. I’ve hit it a few other times – I’m not entirely sure how changes in my code affect the likelihood of error. I can make trivial edits to my code until Lambda starts liking it again, but that’s not a particularly helpful or efficient method of debugging.
- Looking in the Web Inspector console – it’s clean. If this is a JavaScript error, it’s not happening on the client side.
- Searching Google and SO, but I haven’t found anything useful. I’m not sure if this means nothing’s there, or it’s just lost in a sea of unrelated JavaScript errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Turns out, AWS Lambda gets miserable when you print the null byte to stdout.**

At the end of the script, I was grabbing a Terraform plan from S3 and printing to stdout:

```python
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
o = s3.Object(bucket_name, '/path/to/terraform.plan')
print(len(o.get()['Body'].read()))
```

What I didn’t realise originally is that I’d hit the bug iff this last line was executed. If my change earlier in the script caused it to raise an exception, it wouldn't hit this line and the script would complete (albeit with a Python exception). If the rest of the script ran cleanly, the Lambda fell over.

A Terraform plan file is a binary file, so printing it to stdout may include some weird byte strings. After some bisecting, I was able to reduce to two minimal examples. Pasting these into a default Lambda for Python 2.7 can trigger the error.

1. In some cases, I was getting *Internal Server Error*. The following script triggers that reliably:

   ```python
   def lambda_handler(event, context):
       print('\x00')
   ```
2. In other cases, I was getting *null is not an object*. The following script triggers that reliably:

   ```python
   def lambda_handler(event, context):
       print('\x00\x00')
   ```

I don’t think it’s not just the null byte – I get the same behaviour if I mix in `\x01`, `\x02`, and so on.

The lesson here for me is that I should be careful about what I’m printing!